# How to change font in MsgBox

Tags: vbscript

How do you change font in a `MsgBox`?

```
X = MsgBox("I want this to be bold times new roman.")
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't. The dialog displayed via `MsgBox` uses the font that is configured for system dialogs. If you need a custom dialog you need to build a custom dialog, e.g. [like this](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_ui_password.php#InternetExplorer):

```
Sub CustomMsgBox(msg)
  Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  ie.Navigate "about:blank"

  While ie.ReadyState <> 4 : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend

  ie.ToolBar   = False
  ie.StatusBar = False
  ie.Width     = 300
  ie.Height    = 120

  ie.document.body.innerHTML = "<p class='msg'>" & msg & "</p>" & _
    "<p class='ctrl'><input type='hidden' id='OK' name='OK' value='0'>" & _
    "<input type='submit' value='OK' id='OKButton' " &_
    "onclick='document.all.OK.value=1'></p>"

  Set style = ie.document.CreateStyleSheet
  style.AddRule "p.msg", "font-family:times new roman;font-weight:bold;"
  style.AddRule "p.ctrl", "text-align:rightf;"

  ie.Visible = True

  On Error Resume Next
  Do While ie.Document.all.OK.value = 0 
    WScript.Sleep 200
  Loop
  ie.Quit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add the pre /pre tags as shown below so that the format isn't lost. Then I would change the height/width to a standard minimum screen size like 800x400. Then for the visually impaired change the StatusBar to True which enables the "Change zoom level".

```
Sub CustomMsgBox(msg)
  Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  ie.Navigate "about:blank"

  While ie.ReadyState <> 4 : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend

  ie.ToolBar   = False
  ie.StatusBar = True
  ie.Width     = 800
  ie.Height    = 400

  ie.document.body.innerHTML = "<p class='msg'><pre>" & msg & "</pre></p>" & _
    "<p class='ctrl'><input type='hidden' id='OK' name='OK' value='0'>" & _
    "<input type='submit' value='OK' id='OKButton' " &_
    "onclick='document.all.OK.value=1'></p>"

  Set style = ie.document.CreateStyleSheet
  style.AddRule "p.msg", "font-family:times new roman;font-weight:bold;"
  style.AddRule "p.ctrl", "text-align:rightf;"

  ie.Visible = True

  On Error Resume Next
  Do While ie.Document.all.OK.value = 0 
    WScript.Sleep 200
  Loop
  ie.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems like a comment tacked onto another answer rather than an actual answer itself.

Comment: Agreed. It's a minor change.