# How to put URL in helpfile into MsgBox function?

Tags: vbscript, msgbox

I want to have a URL in the helpfile part of the VBScript `MsgBox()` function. How do I do that?

Here is the code:

```
Dim error
Dim helpPath
helpPath = "http://www.example.com/example-support-page"
error = MsgBox("There was an error doing whatever.", vbSystemModal + vbCritical, "Uh oh!")
helpPath = MsgBox("", vbSystemModal + vbMsgBoxHelpButton, "", helpPath)
```

Comment: Don't know why you would think that would work. `helpfile` 
String expression that identifies the Help file to use to provide context-sensitive Help for the dialog box. If helpfile is provided, context must also be provided. Not available on 16-bit platforms. `context` 
Numeric expression that identifies the Help context number assigned by the Help author to the appropriate Help topic. If context is provided, helpfile must also be provided. Not available on 16-bit platforms. That is how Windows Help Files work - file name and help context number. It predates the internet.

Comment: Not sure of any way to get a hyperlink into a msgbox. However, you can format your msgbox as 'Oops - shall we go to the help page?' and use Yes/No buttons then code the 'Yes' option as and open() command with the URL as the parameter to invoke the browser to open via the OS. No reason why that would not work.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34608143/1630171).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this answer and it worked:

> Not sure of any way to get a hyperlink into a msgbox. However, you can format your msgbox as 'Oops - shall we go to the help page?' and use Yes/No buttons then code the 'Yes' option as and open() command with the URL as the parameter to invoke the browser to open via the OS. No reason why that would not work.

- Vanquished Wombat

(I copied and pasted it because I can't seem to mark a comment as an answer.)