# An input box that returns a value when a button is pressed

Tags: vbscript, textbox, return

So basically, I really want a VBS text box with buttons "Abort", "Retry", and "Cancel". Cancel and abort will just close the box, but if retry is pressed it will open up a different file on my computer.

In code words, kinda like this:

```
InputBox("sampleText", "sampleText")
If RETRY==Pressed goto :loop1
:loop1
exit & start sampleText.bat
:end
Else goto :loop2
:loop2
exit
:end
```

Also, I'm very inept at coding things like this, so the syntax on this is probably wrong, and apologies for that. Hopefully I got the point across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `InputBox` builtin dialog doesn't allow specifying which buttons you want to use, but the [`MsgBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw6660x.aspx) dialog does. You can't display the combination Abort/Retry/Cancel, though, only Abort/Retry/Ignore.

```
rc = MsgBox("Message", vbAbortRetryIgnore, "Title")
Select Case rc
    Case vbAbort
        WScript.Echo "User pressed 'Abort'."
    Case vbRetry
        WScript.Echo "User pressed 'Retry'."
    Case vbIgnore
        WScript.Echo "User pressed 'Ignore'."
End Select
```

If you want a message box with the buttons "Abort", "Retry", and "Cancel", or an input box with buttons other than "OK" and "Cancel", you'd have to build a [custom dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34608143/1630171).

Comment: Awesome, this helped a lot.  I meant Retry Abort and Ignore, I just forgot that cancel isn't there.